# cross_val_score return accuracy per class

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like the `cross_val_score` from sklearn function to return the accuracy per each of the classes instead of the average accuracy of all the classes.

Function:

```
sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score(estimator, X, y=None, groups=None,  
       scoring=None, cv=’warn’, n_jobs=None, verbose=0, fit_params=None, 
       pre_dispatch=‘2*n_jobs’, error_score=’raise-deprecating’)
```

[Reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score)

How can I do it?

Comment: You can't do it with `cross_val_score` but you can achieve what you need by doing a `KFold` and fitting the `model` with the fold data, predicting on validation split of the fold and finding the accuracy of the class you need.

Comment: You will need to use [`cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) for that.

Comment: hi guys the reason why I want to achieve this is because the problem I am currently working on requires obtaining accuracy per class. the reason I don't want to do it by hand is because I want to use the "n_jobs" parameter to parelalize the fitting in my CPUs. any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible with `cross_val_score`. The approach you suggest would mean `cross_val_score` would have to return an array of arrays. However, if you look at the source code, you will see that the output of `cross_val_score` has to be :

> ```
> Returns
> -------
> scores : array of float, shape=(len(list(cv)),)
>     Array of scores of the estimator for each run of the cross validation.
> ```

As a result, `cross_val_score` checks if the scoring method you are using is multimetric or not. If it is, it will throw you an error like:

> ValueError: scoring must return a number, got ... instead

#### Edit:

Like it is correctly pointed out by a comment above, an alternative for you is to use `cross_validate` instead. Here is how it would work on the Iris dataset for instance:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

scoring = {'recall0': make_scorer(recall_score, average = None, labels = [0]), 
       'recall1': make_scorer(recall_score, average = None, labels = [1]),
       'recall2': make_scorer(recall_score, average = None, labels = [2])}

cross_validate(DecisionTreeClassifier(),X,y, scoring = scoring, cv = 5, return_train_score = False)
```

Note that this is also supported by the `GridSearchCV` methodology.

NB: You cannot return "accuracy by each class", I guess you meant recall, which is basically the proportions of correct predictions amongst data points that actually belong to a class.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem I am solving requires obtaining the accuracy of each of the classes. I do not want to do it by hand since I would like to make use of the "n_jobs" methods to parallelize the CV fitting. any suggestions on this?

Comment: Edited my answer to present an alternative option

Comment: why are you defining the function recall? why not just call `sklearn.metrics.recall_score`?

Comment: also, I am trying to get this integrated with `sklearn.metrics.classification_report` can you include in your code how would you do this integration?

Comment: Edited to add <code>recall_score</code>, I agree it is cleaner that way. As for the classification report, it is not possible directly, however, you can take each of the metrics in the classification report, add them to the scorer just like the recalls (you can do the same for precision for instance) and thus build your own classification report

Comment: you are right. it should be very straight forward to calculate the report from the obtained scores